# How to print the strings having repeating characters?

Tags: python, string, permutation

The question is that:

*Suppose I have a string `S='ABC'`, then I want the output to be this list`['AAA','BBB','CCC','AAB','ABB','AAC','ACC','BBC','BCC']`*

How do I achieve this result?

**Edit:** Thanks to **@Breno Monteiro**, I came up with the solution based on the example he had shown. What I did was produced the list `['AAA','BBB','CCC']` at first, by multiplying 3 with each of the characters. After that, I replaced the first and second index of the each of the elements in `['AAA','BBB','CCC']` by the second character in the string i.e., if the character is `'A'` then its replaced by `'B'`, if its `'C'`, then its replaced by `'A'` and so on and so forth. So the real output came out to be `['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'BAA', 'BBA', 'CBB', 'CCB', 'ACC', 'AAC']`

**My code:**

```
string='ABC'
K=3
output=['AAA','BBB','CCC','AAB','ABB','AAC','ACC','BBC','BCC']
s=""
exp_output,temp=[],[]
ind=1
#including all repeating characters in the string
for i in string:
    s+=i*K
    exp_output.append(s)
    s=""

#including all repeating characters by the first and second index
for i in exp_output:
    for j in range(K-1):
        i=i.replace(i[j],string[ind%len(string)],1)
        temp.append(i)
        #print(temp)
    ind+=1
exp_output.extend(temp)

print(exp_output)
```

Comment: Why is `'ABC'` in your output? That doesn't have any repeating characters.

Comment: Homework questions really need to show some effort to get taken seriously here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to repeat characters in Python is:

```
character = 'A'
repeat_times = 3
print(character * repeat_times)
```

> Output: AAA

You can also use Python strings as a list of characters, like this:

```
characters = 'ABC'
repeat_times = 3

for character in characters:
    print(character*repeat_times)
```

> Output: AAA, BBB, CCC